# how to change serialized JSON structure django rest framwork

Tags: python, json, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I'm wondering if it possible to change structure of my JSON that im sedinding out.
currenyly it looks like this:

```
{
    "para_subject": {
      "discipline": "MATAN"
    },
    "para_room": {
      "room": "210"
    },
    "para_professor": {
        "user": {
            "username": "yyyy",
            "email": "yyyy.yyyy@gmail.com",
            "first_name": "yyyy",
            "last_name": "yyy"
         },
        "middle_name": "xxxxxx"
     },

}
```

what is the best way to change it to this:

```
  {
    "discipline": "MATAN",
    "room": "210",
    "para_professor": {
        "username": "yyyy",
         "email": "yyyy.yyyy@gmail.com",
         "first_name": "yyyy",
         "last_name": "yyy"
         "middle_name": "xxxx"
         },
    }
```

UPDATE:
Adding serializer and model upon to the request in comments

Object Serializer:

```
class ParaSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    para_subject = DisciplineSerializer()
    para_room = RoomSerializer()
    para_professor = ProfessorProfileForScheduleSerializer(read_only=True)
    para_number = ParaTimeSerializer()
    para_day = WorkingDaySerializer()
    # para_group = StudentGroupSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Para
        fields = (
            'para_subject',
            'para_room',
            'para_professor',
            'para_number',
            'para_day',
            'para_group',
            'week_type'
        )
```

Object Model:

```
class Para(models.Model):

    class Meta(object):
        verbose_name = u"Class"
        verbose_name_plural = u"Classes"

    para_subject = models.ForeignKey(
        'Disciplines',
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        verbose_name=u"Discipline"
    )
    para_room = models.ForeignKey(
        'Rooms',
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        verbose_name=u"Room"
    )
    para_professor = models.ForeignKey(
        'students.ProfileModel',
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        verbose_name=u"Professor"
    )
    para_number = models.ForeignKey(
        'ParaTime',
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        verbose_name=u"Class Starts/Ends"
    )
    para_day = models.ForeignKey(
        WorkingDay,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        verbose_name=u"Working day")

    para_group = models.ForeignKey(
        'StudentGroupModel',
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        verbose_name=u"Student Group"
    )
    week_type = models.BooleanField(
        default=True,
        verbose_name=u"Is week even"
    )

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s %s" % (self.para_subject, self.para_room)
```

Comment: Please add your serializer and corresponding model.

Comment: Done. let me know if other parts of code needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `discipline` and `room` fields with `source` parameters on `ParaSerializer`.

These fields will fetch the value from the `source` mentioned and will be included in the output.

```
class ParaSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer)
    # define 'discipline' and 'room' fields
    discipline = serializers.CharField(source='para_subject.discipline', read_only=True)
    room = serializers.CharField(source='para_room.room', read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Para
        fields = (
            'discipline', # include this field
            'room', # include this field
            'para_professor',
            'para_number',
            'para_day',
            'para_group',
            'week_type'
        )
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into it

Answer (score 3):

It depends of the serializers/models you use, but in general can use serializers looking like this:

```
class Serializer1(serializers.Serializer):
    discipline = serializers.CharField()
    room = serializers.IntegerField()
    para_professer = Serializer2()

class Serializer2(serializers.Serializer):
    username = serializers.CharField()
    email = serializers.CharField()
    first_name = serializers.CharField()
    last_name = serializers.CharField()
    middle_name = serializers.CharField()
```

Here you can find the nested serializer doc of the django rest framework
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships

Based on the new infos in your question you could overwrite the .to_representation() method of your serializer:

```
class ParaSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Para
        fields = (
            'para_subject',
            'para_room',
            'para_professor',
            'para_number',
            'para_day',
            'para_group',
            'week_type'
        )

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        return {
            'discipline': instance.para_subject.name,
            'room': instance.para_room.number,
            'para_professor': {
                'username': instance.para_professor.username,
                'email': instance.para_professor.email,
                'first_name': instance.para_professor.first_name,
                'last_name': instance.para_professor.last_name,
                'middle_name': instance.para_professor.middle_name
            }
        }
```

Comment: that is similar to what i'm doing, but model has many foreign key relations which i think is a cause of this effect. I have updated the ticket with my model and serializer for this model.

Comment: Have a look on the SlugRelatedField: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#slugrelatedfield

Comment: doesn't look like what I need :(

Comment: Thanks for looking into it