# Django-rest , return customized Json

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Hi i'm having this code for a backend query

```py
class HexList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = HexSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        hex_list = Hex.objects.filter(game_id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        return hex_list
```

That returns this Json:

```
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "game_id": 0,
        "position": 3,
        "resource": "NO",
        "token": 0
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "game_id": 0,
        "position": 5,
        "resource": "WO",
        "token": 0
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "game_id": 0,
        "position": 6,
        "resource": "BR",
        "token": 4
    }
]
```

What i would like it to return is the same data, but with in the shape of a Json like  something like this:

```
    "hexes":[
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "game_id": 0,
                    "position": 3,
                    "resource": "NO",
                    "token": 0
                },
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "game_id": 0,
                    "position": 5,
                    "resource": "WO",
                    "token": 0
                },
                {
                    "id": 4,
                    "game_id": 0,
                    "position": 6,
                    "resource": "BR",
                    "token": 4
                }
            ]
}
```

I've tried this :

```py
class HexList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = HexSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        hex_list = Hex.objects.filter(game_id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        return Response({'hexes': hex_list})
```

And i'm getting a ContentNotRenderedError Exception

What should i do? Thanks in advance

Comment: The `return Response({'hexes': hex_list})` doesn't work because the `get_queryset` function is expecting to return a queryset, not a response

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to change serialized JSON structure django rest framwork](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38142137/how-to-change-serialized-json-structure-django-rest-framwork)

Answer (score 2):

As for your `get_queryset` method, it should return the queryset you want to use, not the `Response`. For fidgeting with `Response` you should overwrite the `list` method. Something like this should work, however i did not test it.

```
class HexList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = HexSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        hex_list = Hex.objects.filter(game_id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        return hex_list

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        hexes = self.get_queryset()
        serializer = self.get_serializer(hexes, many=True)
        return Response({'hexes': serializer.data})
```